# Excel 2010 Cell Validation - Grouped List

Tags: excel

Is it possible (without the use of user forms, or form controls) to have a grouped validation list in-cell, where the group title cannot be selected. So for example:

**Fruit**
Apple
Banana
**Veg**
Potato
Carrot

I feel like I've been searching for an absolute age now, and I'm getting no where fast. The reason I cannot use form controls as that there are 8 sheets, each with a few thousand rows (possible) and each entry must have this selection. I have done this before with dependant lists across multiple columns but I'd like to trim everything down.

Any ideas? I don't want a clear cut solution if one exists, just a nudge in the right direction. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Very hard to understand.

Comment: Basically, you can have in-cell validation in the form of drop down lists. I would like the ability to group certain items together, separated by a header which cannot be selected. [Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) in HTML, but I would like to apply the same premise in Excel

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that since no property exist in excel to do your expected task without Userform.